# apps script to attach all files to email that exist in a folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Below is where I am currently at with my code.  It works just fine to attach one file.  It is only attaching the last file in the folder.  I want it to attach all files.

```
   function email() {   

   // Get attachments folder
  var attachementFolderId = values[cell][11];
  Logger.log("Attachement Folder ID:  " + attachementFolderId)
  var getAttachementFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(attachementFolderId).getFiles();

   // Get all files from the folder
 var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(attachementFolderId).getFiles();
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   var attachements = file.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
   Logger.log(attachements)
 }

     MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: recipient,
     subject: address,
     htmlBody: "Hello <br><br>" +
               "Address:  " + address + "<br><br>" +
               "Description: " + description,
    attachments: [attachements]
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is not right. try like below :

```
var attachements = [];
while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   attachements.push(file.getAs(MimeType.PDF));// the push method add elements to the attachements array
   Logger.log(attachements)
 }
```

And in the end :

```
 MailApp.sendEmail({
 to: recipient,
 subject: address,
 htmlBody: "Hello <br><br>" +
           "Address:  " + address + "<br><br>" +
           "Description: " + description,
attachments: attachements
})
```

Comment: ok, I'll try your suggestion as that is one way I was trying but didn't get it to work.  The solution I have below works, so why do you say it's not right?

Comment: I used your method and it works.  I agree your method is the better option but seems as my method also works.

Comment: You're right, your code wasn't wrong, I probably misread it since it is not a very conventional way to populate an array :-)   Thanks for accepting this answer.

Comment: thanks, I marked mine as answered also:)  Ya, I was using straight up basic method of adding to an array.  It works, but ya, your way is better

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Probably simple mistake to experienced coders...all I did was create an array and each time it finds a file and get's it as a blob, add it to the array.

```
attachmentsArray[attachmentsArray.length] = attachmentFiles;
```

Is the code I added just below

```
var attachmentFiles = file.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
```

Then instead of

```
attachments: [attachements]
```

I put this

```
attachments: attachmentsArray
```